# no stationary distribution with none-vanishing limit of transition probability

Tags: markov-process, stationary-processes

We know that irreducible Markov chains can be separated into the two cases:
(1) All limits of transition probabilities vanish: $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{ij}^{(n)} = 0$ for all i,j in state space S.
(2) All limits of transition probabilities do not vanish: $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{ij}^{(n)} \neq  0$ for all i,j in state space S, including cases where limits of transition probabilities do not exists.

If the chain has a stationary distribution, then it is in case (2), for example, see Vanishing Together Corollary in Rosenthal's "A First Look at Stochastic Process". Is it possible that a chain is in case (2) but has no stationary distribution?

---

Edit: Based on John's answer and user8675309's comment, an irreducible Markov chain has the following cases: 
(1) $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{ij}^{(n)}$ exists for all i,j in S, where: 
$\quad$ (1.1) $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{ij}^{(n)} = 0$ for all i,j in S, then there is no stationary distribution. 
$\quad$ (1.2) $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{ij}^{(n)} > 0$ for all i,j in S, then there a stationary distribution is given by $$\pi_j = \frac{lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{ij}^{(n)}}{\sum_{k \in S}lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{ik}^{(n)}}$$ for all j in S. 
(2) For some i,j in S, $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{ij}^{(n)}$ does not exists. 
$\quad$ (2.1) There is a stationary distribution: For example, S = {1,2} and $p_{12} = p_{21} = 1$ and the stationary distribution is given by $\pi_1 = \pi_2 = \frac{1}{2}$. 
$\quad$ (2.2) There is no stationary distribution.

Is (2.2) possible (assuming the chain is irreducible)? If so, what's an example?

If the chain is finite and irreducible, then all states are positive recurrent and the chain has a stationary distribution. So for (2.2) to hold, it has to be a chain with infinite state space and mean recurrence time zero for all states. I wonder whether this implies $lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{ij}^{(n)} = 0$ for all i,j in S.

I know $1/m_i = lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E_i(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}1_{X_k=i}) = lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}E_i(1_{X_k=i})=lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}P_i(1_{X_k=i})= lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}p_{ii}^{k} = 0$. 
But I don't see how this imply $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}p_{ii}^{n}=0$.

Comment: This question is ill-posed.  In the case of an irreducible positive recurrent periodic chain you cannot say $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{ij}^{(n)} =  0$ and it's troubling to say that something that doesn't exist $\neq 0$ i.e. $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_{ij}^{(n)} \neq  0$ because the limit does not exist so your assertion that  *"We know that irreducible Markov chains can be separated into the two cases"* is problematic.  A more careful discussion would e.g. observe that these are bounded sequences, so you can can discuss their convergent subsequences or better: the time-average.

Comment: Hi user8675309, I have adjusted the cases. Is (2.2) now possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how to start with the convergent subsequences, since a divergent sequence can have multiple subsequences converging to different values. Also, does time-average always converge? The boundedness is not enough to make the time-average converge.

Comment: **(a)** in LaTeX use "\lim" not "lim".  **(b)** yes time average converges (**what text you are using?**) and it's a semi-easy argument (depending on the text, via elementary renewal theorem though there are direct countable state markov chain approaches).  **(c)** re: convergent sub-sequences -- your first case is properly characterized as having *all* such sub-sequences converge to zero and the other one is properly characterized as having some subsequence that converges to something other than zero. There's other approaches (e.g. ensemble average) but overall, time average is my vote.

Comment: @user8675309 Thanks so much for your help! I'm using Jeffery Rosenthal's _A First Look At Stochastic Process_. I haven't learnt the renewal theorem yet. Is any reference for the convergence of time average through direct countable state Markov chain approaches?

Comment: To be clear there are various things referred to as the renewal theorem -- the main one is difficult (Blackwell/ Feller-Erdos-Pollard) but the elementary renewal theorem is much simpler.  I like the treatment of countable state markov chains in the book by Ross and Pekoz and had thought it developed the time average directly but I'm not seeing it.  *One approach to get to the heart of the matter: just state that you assume your chain is aperioidic.* Feller and many others will state that periodicity is a nuisance and they deal with it after developing the interesting stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in case (2) the limit probabilities $\pi_j:=\lim_n p_{i,j}^{(n)}$ are all $>0$, add to $1$, and form a stationary distribution.

Comment: Despite what OP wrote, this limit need not exist.